# PHP Error Unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, sql

A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'footer' in 'where clause'

SELECT `submenus`.`text_ge` as sub_title, `staties`.`title_ge` as stat_title, `staties`.`id` as stat_id FROM (`submenus`) JOIN `staties` ON `staties`.`submenu_id` = `submenus`.`id` WHERE `footer` = 1 GROUP BY `staties`.`id`

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\web\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

I have some problems here, I don't know what to do.

Comment: I think the error speaks for itself

Comment: does the column footer exist in one of your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Does footer exist?

If it does, then specify:

```
<table_name>.footer = 1
```

in the where clause.

Comment: I forgot everything friend where to put exactly? I have MVC application

Comment: in the where clause replace `footer` with `table_name.footer`

Comment: 871 491 192           6264   this is my team viewer codes, if you come in to my computer and solve this problem positive feedback from me plus Respect

Comment: @Programmer: Stack Overflow is not a platform for soliciting free labour. Please edit your question to show the tables you have used in your query, and indicate where the column `footer` might be stored. You may be looking in the wrong table.